# Want to add a "Open" link to a SharePoint Document Library

Tags: document-library

I have a SharePoint document library that's been migrated over from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2019 (we're running SharePoint on-premise).

In SharePoint 2013 the library was hosted in a Records Management Site Collections which made heavy use of Document IDs. In a lot of instances, the document library views included the `Document ID` column as a link to the document. This was great because it was a fixed-length column that allowed them to display much more metadata on the library list screen. The problem is that the Document ID feature is not enabled on the SharePoint 2019 Site Collection the documents were migrated into, and so we cannot continue to use the Document ID column in SharePoint 2019. *NB: We cannot enable the feature for various reasons*.

The library I'm working with has over 6000 documents in it. Ideally, I would like to replace the Document ID column with a generic "Open" hyperlink to the PDF, DWG, etc. Any ideas on how we can create something like that?

Comment: Are you using modern libraries? If so, then column formatting can help to generate a link using the document's metadata. If you provide more details about the columns available (internal name/type) a more specific answer can be given.

Comment: Hi theChrisKent, yes, I am using modern libraries. It's a standard document library, so I would imagine all of the standard fields would be there. Which fields specifically are you looking for? I appreciate the response, I'm just not 100% what you mean when you say "more details about the columns available".